# Space of solutions to a system of first-order PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I would like to know what is known (both explanations and references) about the spaces of smooth solutions to linear systems of PDEs of the following form:

Let $g_{1},...,g_{n}$ be smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with the integrability condition $\partial{g_{i}}/\partial{x^{j}}=\partial{g_{j}}/\partial{x^{i}}$ and consider the space of smooth functions $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ satisfying $\partial{f}/\partial{x^{i}}=fg_{i}$ for all $i$.

Similarly for the $g_{i}$ and $f$ being holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, and replacing $\mathbb{R}^{n}, \mathbb{C}^{n}$ with open contractible subsets.

My hope is that the answer is there is a unique solution, up to scaling.

Comment: You can rewrite your system as $\vec{\nabla} \ln f = \vec{g}$...

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: Also, what if $f$ has zeroes and what if I'm interested in complex values? I would be happy to say that there exists a contractible open cover of my space over which there is a unique solution on each covering set, if that would help solve the problem about branches of the logarithm.

Comment: Note that $f$ can only have zeros where $\vec{g}$ has singularities. Remember that $\vec{g}$ is the given and $f$ the unknown, so that when looking at the latter in terms of the former we are working with exponentials instead of logarithms and therefore don't have to worry about branches.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the system of PDEs as $\vec{\nabla} \ln f = \vec{g}$. If the vector field $\vec{g}$ has a potential function (which I believe is true if and only if its Jacobian matrix is symmetric, but I don't recall the source of this fact off-hand), then we may denote the potential as $G$ and solve the system as $f=\exp G$, which is unique up to rescalings. (There may be a negative sign in the exponential depending on what definition of potential you're using.) On the other hand, if $\vec{g}$ doesn't have a potential then it isn't a gradient field and hence no $f$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

anon's answer is almost complete, here I'm filling important gaps.

As anon pointed your system is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \ln(f)= g_i$ then by Froebenius theorem, the PDE system has a solution if and only if the $\nabla g$ is a symmetric matrix, which is true given your assumption that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} g_j= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} g_j$.

Moreover, given initial data, Frobenius theorem also gives you a unique local solution for you system, see page 92 of this paper (http://nyjm.albany.edu/j/2004/10-6.pdf‎) for the Frobenius theorem in a PDE/local coordinates/classical version. Perhaps with your additional assumptions about the domain, you maybe able to extent it to a global solution.